# Proving that $fib(n) < (\frac53)^n$ for $n \ge 1$ by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I know this has been shown before here but no post really answered my question. I had this problem given to me as an induction practice problem and I couldn't solve it without help. When I got the help I needed, no one could explain to me at a basic level why you were able to perform some of these steps. The proof is below

> Base case, $N = 1$
>
> So, $f_1 = 1$ by the definition of Fibonacci numbers.
>
> Then $f_1 < (\frac53)$ is true.
>
> Then assume for all $n \geq 1, f_n < (\frac53)^n$ is true.
>
> Then $f_n + f_{n-1} < (\frac53)^n + (\frac53)^{n-1}$ by the definition
> of Fibonacci numbers.
>
> Then $f_{n+1} < (\frac53)^n + (\frac53)^{n-1}$
>
> Then $f_{n+1} < (\frac53)^{n-1}(1 + \frac53)$ by factoring out $
> > (\frac53)^{n-1}$ from the right side
>
> Then $f_{n+1} < (\frac53)^{n-1}(\frac83)$
>
> (now this is where I got lost and had to get help)
>
> Then note that $(\frac83) < (\frac53)^2$ and therefore $f_n <
> > (\frac53)^2$
>
> Then by substitution $f_{n+1} < (\frac53)^{n-1}(\frac53)^2$
>
> Then $f_{n+1} < (\frac53)^{n+1}$
>
> QED.

Now I understand most of this proof. I just dont understand how you can, essentially out of the blue, just state that $\frac83 < (\frac53)^2$ and use this directly in the proof. I understand the statement is true, but how can you just substitute them for each other? If anyone can fill in the blanks for me I would really appreciate it. I feel like I should understand this but I don't.

Thank you!

Comment: I know this isn't quite the point you are asking, but you actually need to verify that the inequality holds not only for $f_1$, but also for $f_2$.

Comment: There are many proofs where numbers that make things work appear out of the blue. It is a fairly standard practice. Usually these numbers come from some side calculations that may not need to be included formally in the proof. This does make them hard to follow at times.

Comment: Also, I don't think "therefore $f_n < (5/3)^2$" should be there. The important thing is $f_{n+1} < (5/3)^{n-1} (8/3)$, and $(5/3)^{n-1}(8/3) < (5/3)^{n-1} (5/3)^2$.

Comment: @braindead Why is this necessary if the base case is only for $N=1$?

Comment: Think about how your induction argument works. In your proof, you are using $f_{n} < (5/3)^{n} AND f_{n-1} <(5/3)^{n-1}$ to prove that $f_{n+1} < (5/3)^{n+1}$. Now, you also have $f_1 < (5/3)$. How does it follow that $f_2 < (5/3)^2$?

Comment: @anon123 The Fibonacci series has two base cases (the first two numbers); since you need to add the two previous numbers together to get the next one, you must start with two.

Comment: @Braindead Is it because that $f_2 < (5/3)^2$ by the induction hypothesis?

Answer (score 2):

We'd like to show that $f_{n+1}< (5/3)^{n+1}$. But all we can get from the induction assumption is $f_{n+1}<(5/3)^{n-1}(8/3)$.

So, what is wrong with the term we are dealing with? It is lacking a factor of $(5/3)^2$ (Since $(5/3)^{n+1}=(5/3)^{n-1}(5/3)^2$), but there is a factor of $8/3$ too much. So what would happen if we replaced the $8/3$ by the desired amount of $(5/3)^2$? Luckily, $8/3$ is less than $(5/3)^2$, thus it makes the result greater if we replace it. Thus, we get

$$f_{n+1}<(5/3)^{n-1}(8/3) < (5/3)^{n-1}(5/3)^2 = (5/3)^{n+1},$$
the desired inequality.

Note that, apart from needing to check the base case for $n=2$ as well, there is a crucial mistake in your induction: You should not assume that the assertion you want to show is true for all $n \geq 1$, as this is assuming that what you want to show is already true. What you should assume is that there is a number $n\leq 2$ such that $f_n <(5/3)^n$ and $f_{n-1} <(5/3)^{n-1}$. You are actually using only these in your proof, it's just the start of your induction step which is phrased wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

Look why $(8/3) < (5/3)^2$:

We have: $(5/3)^2 = (25/9)$
and so $(5/3)^2 - (8/3) = (25/9) - (8/3) = (25 - 24)/9 = 1/9 > 0$

Thus, $(8/3) < (5/2)^2$

So, for every $x$ strictly positive we have: $ x*(8/3) < x*(5/3)^2$ 
Now, just substitute $x$ with $(5/3)^{n-1}$ to complete your proof.